# If I stand on my head for a while will I get healthier?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine, yoga

I've read that standing on your head (called [sirsasana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirsasana) by [hatha yoga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatha_yoga) practicioners) does something to the blood flow to the brain and hence increase your health or something.

Partial claims were made here: http://www.naturalnews.com/023880.html

Following claim can be found at [Sirsasana wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirsasana):

> Practitioners of yoga believe that, like most inverted positions, the practice of sirsasana may increase the flow of blood to the brain, improve memory and other functions of the cerebrum. Included in the physiological benefits are the drainage of blood and lymph which are held in reserve in the legs. Any inversion, when the legs are held over the heart, helps to move stored fluids into the core for oxygenation, filtration and elimination of metabolic/cellular wastes.

Is it true? if yes - how many minutes?

Comment: Just some notes: I think someone sooner or later will complain but you should provide some evidence in your question that your claim is notable. On a side note: I can't edit without changing 6 chars, so I'll tell you here that *everyday* is an adverb, while in your question, it should be *every day*, like this. :)

Comment: There was an episode of Fresh Prince of Bel Air wherein Phil purchased a device that you can strap yourself to in order to hang upside down, purportedly for your health. This would be a related form of therapy without the pressure on your skull. Unfortunately, it's very difficult to google anything "upside down" when it comes to Fresh Prince thanks to the song's lyrics.

Comment: Of course you will. While you are standing on your head, you cannot also be munching away on Fritos, a Big Mac, or a supersized soft drink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many practitioners of yoga advise against the practice, according to a recent NY Times article (["How yoga can wreck your body"](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/01/08/magazine/how-yoga-can-wreck-your-body.html)) discusses risks of this sport, with frequent mention of injuries caused by headstands. Most of the problems seem related to excessive pressure on the cervical vertebrae. Other problems mentioned are retinal tearing (due to pressure on/around the eyeballs?), blood flow disruption and nerve damage.

The article makes no mention of any effects of increased blood flow to the brain or whether inversion can cause this, nor does it address any claims of unfiltered or unoxygenated fluids stored in the legs.